# Python - Class methods with input

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

How can I create a method in a class with a user input?

What argument should I pass when I am calling the method ?

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''     

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, newName):
        newName = input ('Inserire nome:')
        self._name = newName

studente = Student()
studente.setName(newName)
```

Comment: wats da doubt...didnt get you

Comment: my doubt is that I do not know how to pass "newName" to "setMethod" recalled

Comment: you are already doing it.. studente.setName(newName). Not clear yet

Comment: Yes, my friend. But that will not work, he says that "newName" is not defined

Comment: ya obvisously.... u need to send some string value..... den it gets passed as argument.... how do u want to handle

Comment: you can take the input outside the class.... and then send it as argument..
newName= input ('Inserire nome:') use this outside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, newName):
        self._name = newName

studente = Student()
newName = input('Inserire nome:')
studente.setName(newName)
```

You were defining the input inside the method itself but passing the variable outside. So the variable `newName` wasn't defined outside. Let me know if it doesn't work. I haven't tested it, but seems like the conspicuous error here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want correctly, 
why dont you try to ask for an input when initialsing class instance?

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input('Enter name> ')

X = MyClass() # when executing that line, you'll be asked for a name to input
```

Then you'll be able to acces `name` attribute by `X.name` and set it to whatever you'd like to by `X.name = foo`

Comment: that's for python 3+

Answer (score -1):

You could also play with the builtin `setattr` and dismiss the explicit setters/getters:

```
class Student:
    pass

student = Student()
newName = input('Inserire nome:')
setattr(student, 'name', newName)
```